# making an app in flutter, following error shows up. Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: flutter, dart, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies, android-manifest

Built a project in flutter, earlier had an issue with API keys.

now, keep coming across this error despite updating all dependencies to latest version, correcting issues to AndroidManifest.xml file
this is the detailed error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Could not create task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
   > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

not sure why this  keeps showing up, ChatGPT suggest there could be build issues

Ran `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` repeatedly and have the same issue.

any solutions for this issue?